# Move-SPUser not update Editor of listitem

Tags: powershell, user, move

I have to do a script to migrate user because of change domain.
From DOM1\user1 to DOM2\user2

When i do

```
$web = $spsite.openweb()
        $userToReplace = $web.EnsureUser($oldLogin)

        if($userToReplace)
        {
            $userReplaced = "i:0#.w|$newLogin"
            #$userToReplace ="i:0#.w|$oldLogin"
            Move-SPUser -Confirm:$false -Identity $userToReplace -NewAlias  $userReplaced -IgnoreSID 
        }
```

It changes the permission to the new account but when i go to a listitem updated by DOM1\user1
If i click on the Modified by, it goes to the old userid and not the new

Answer (score 0):

I have found something that worked for me.

It is kind of forcing it to sync again:

```
Get-SPUser –Web http://sharepointsite | Set-SPUser –SyncFromAD
```

You will probably get some error like ***Set-SPUser : Cannot get the full name or e-mail address of user "c:0(.s|true"*.**, but nothing to worry about

Comment: Thanks for your proposition. I have user profile is it ok with this?